# Running Flask server with Celery in the background

Tags: linux, flask, celery

I have to run my script (which is Flask server), as well as the Celery worker in order for my application to work with two commands:

```
python3 my_application.py
celery -A my_application.celery worker
```

I want this to run on my Ubuntu VM in the background and also start again automatically when the machine has restarted.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to make two Linux services. One for your Flask-based service, and the other for Celery. Celery has a whole section in the documentation - [Daemonization](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) - to explain the ways to do exactly what you want. Most modern Linux distributions (Ubuntu included) use [systemd](https://systemd.io/), so I recommend getting familiar with it.